# Cache or preload some variables in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on a PHP/MySQL based product search application. In that application we have some global variables which are being populated from database. Since these variables are common for all search requests, it's unnecessary to populate each time a search request comes to the server.

I have seen some recommendations of using memcache and APC but the problem is that we don't have access to install these in the server. Is there any convenient way to keep these variables initialized only once and use for all server requests?

Example of some variables:

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT brand_name FROM brands");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        foreach ($result->rows as $row) {
            if ($row['brand_name'] != '') {
                $GLOBALS["filter"]['brand_name'][] = $row['brand_name'];
            }
        }
    }
```

It contains the brand names which used in the search queries for comparison. Similarly we have many other predefined globals.

Comment: Did this work? Generally global variables can be trouble, but if this helps solve your problem it might not be a terrible idea. It's always a good idea to document functions that manipulate globals so their impact is well known. Nothing worse than some other bit of code wanting control over `$GLOBALS['filter']` and the two run into conflict.

Comment: @tadman I have global variables in the format $GLOBALS["filter"]['brand_name'], $GLOBALS["filter"]['categories'], and so on. I can change the variable from global to any other variable but I need a solution so that it does not initialize for each server request.

Comment: How often does the data in the `brands` table get changed?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus very rarely, once in a couple of months. We can think these values as static.

Comment: On which PHP version is the website running?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - PHP Version 5.6.22

Comment: Perfect, please see my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120177/discussion-between-mainuddin-and-monkeyzeus).

Comment: @Mainuddin Any luck?

Answer (score 1):

If you have [opcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.opcache.php) available then you might be able to do something like this:

**disclaimer:** I have not tested this nor do I have experience with opcache functions or behavior.

---

**Scheduled task (monthly? manual? automatic? idk, you figure it out)**

```
$result = $this->db->query("SELECT brand_name FROM brands");

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    $temp_file = '/path/to/cached/file/brands_cache.'.microtime(true).'.php';

    $final_file = '/path/to/cached/file/brands_cache.php';

    file_put_contents($temp_file, '<?php $GLOBALS["filter"]["brand_name"] = [];');

    foreach ($result->rows as $row) {
        if ($row['brand_name'] != '') {
            file_put_contents($temp_file, '$GLOBALS["filter"]["brand_name"][] = \''.str_replace("'", "\\'", $row['brand_name']).'\';', FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }

    rename($temp_file, $final_file);

    if(opcache_compile_file($final_file))
    {
        echo $final_file.' has been cached';
    }
    else
    {
        echo $final_file.' could not be cached';
    }
}
```

**Your search engine**

```
require_once('/path/to/cached/file/brands_cache.php');

// Feel free to use $GLOBALS["filter"]['brand_name']
```